# How to add KeyStore file protected with password to zip in java

Tags: java, spring, zip, keystore, pfx

I created KeyStore file protected with the password

```
CertificateFactorycertFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(certyfikat);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)  
certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(null,null);
ks.setCertificateEntry("alias", cert);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.pfx");
ks.store(fos, "yourPassword".toCharArray());
```

Is this right way to add password protection to KeyStore?

I want to return this in the zip file. I tried ZipOutputStream and ZipEntry, but using ZipOutputStream.write() can handle only byte[].

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("cert.pfx");
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
zos.write(ks???);
```

How can I convert KeyStore to byte[]?

Is there any other way to create a zip with KeyStore?

Maybe .pfx file should be created in another way rather than with KeyStore class?

Comment: Is the KeyStore class Serializable? Or maybe just read `test.pfx` in as a byte array?

Comment: What do you mean Serializable? I cant read test.pfx because i cant save it in client memory. I need to return it in a zip file. Client send request and as a response he gets zip file where pfx is included

Comment: But you have an output stream? `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.pfx");` Can't you use `ZipOutputStream` as the output stream?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `FileOutputStream` should work.

Replace

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.pfx");
ks.store(fos, "yourPassword".toCharArray());
```

With

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ks.store(bos, "yourPassword".toCharArray());
byte keystore[] = bos.toByteArray();
```